# Clear object generated by URL.createObjectURL()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I use URL.createObjectURL() on my input type file to pass URL to img.src to tell the browser to load the provided image.

Here's my code:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" onchange="document.getElementById('image-container').src = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0])">
<img id="image-container"/>
```

I would like to make a remove button to clear the object so user can browse for another image. I have tried to pass empty string by making **.src = ""** but it doesn't work.

```
<button type="button" ng-click="document.getElementById('image-container').src = ""><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
```

Can anyone suggest what should I do to remove the object created if I persist to keep using URL.createObjectURL() ?

Answer (score 1):

This question has probably already been answered by many, but you can make use of the method `revokeObjectURL()` to release an object URL. The `URL.createObjectURL()` method creates a DOMString containing a URL representing the object (in this case a file) given in the parameter. This URL lifetime would be tied to the document selection in the window on which it was created. The new file's URL would be the specified file/blob object. Now if you want to release this URL based on the user's new selection, a simple call to the static method `revokeObjectURL()` would do the trick, like so:

```
if(event.target.files.length !== 0){
     this.setState({
          src: URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]),
     });
}
else {
     this.setState({
          src: URL.revokeObjectURL(event.target.files[0]),
     });
}
```

Since we want to release the object URL upon a user's reselection of a new file (or lack thereof), calling `revokeObjectURL()` lets the browser know not to keep the reference to the file any longer (essentially resetting what we did with `createObjectURL()`).

Answer (score 0):

You should be using data bindings to do this instead. Then, I would display the image conditionally.

```
// Controller
this.src = "";
this.fileSelected = $event => {
  this.src = $window.URL.createObjectURL($event.target.files[0]);
}

// Template
<input type="file" accept="image/*"
  ng-change="ctrl.fileSelected($event)">
<img ng-if="ctrl.src" ng-src="ctrl.src">

<button type="button" ng-click="ctrl.src = ''">
  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
</button>
```

Comment: I've tried your answer but it shows TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of null

Comment: @Anthonius I need more information about your setup to debug this.  I suspect you are not using `controllerAs` set to `ctrl`. You can set it to anything or just use `$scope` but using `controllerAs` is preferred.

Comment: In the controller I use  
  
`$scope.src = "";`
`$scope.fileSelected = function(event) {  
      $scope.src = $window.URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);  
}`  

and in the template I write  
  
`<input type = "file" accept = "image/*"   
           ng-change="fileSelected($event)">  
<img ng-if="src" ng-src="src">`
  
  
`<button type="button" ng-click="src=''">  
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>  
</button>`